# How to set the focus to the JTable cell if validation fails in java?

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

Every time it is setting focus to first cell of any row after validation. I need to set the focus to particular cell in any row, not the first cell.Here in my code every time the row is changing, but every time the column value comming as 0 and i am unable to find from where this method is calling.

```
public class TestRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
{

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {

                        if(mandatoryValue == true)
                        {
                            setBackground(Color.RED);

                        }
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: please whats TableCellRenderer has something with the Focus, as aside there no problem to set selection to the desired row & column by toggling with Selection,

Comment: if you want to toggling with selection(s) in JTables view, that is already visible, then the easiest of the ways is by using [JTable#changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#changeSelection(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean))

Comment: have to play with SelectionMode, maybe it can be important

Comment: You need to show how `TestRenderer` is used in your code ?

Comment: The code you posted makes absolutely no sense and does not implement TableCellRenderer. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.